# SFML with Netbeans error: undefined reference to 'sf::microseconds(long long)"

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans, sfml

I'm trying to set up SFML to work in netbeans and I keep getting the error shown below.
I'm using the TDM 5.1.0 compiler linked on the SFML download page, and followed all the instructions for setting up the dependencies in netbeans: defined the directories in Path, SFML_STATIC, added the libraries properly in the Linker tab.
The IDE even autocompletes the things I want to use. Something that might be of note is the fact that it seems like the things that are blue in the autocomplete dropdown seem fine (such as WindowHandle) but anything red causes this error. I don't know enough about netbeans to know what these colours mean.

I've looked up other similar questions and I've tried things like changing the order of the libraries, nothing works. I wanted to install MinGW 7.3.0 in case it's just the TDM compiler not working, but I have no idea how to install it - there's no exe and adding the directories in Path doesn't make it show up in Netbeans.

[screenshot of the autocomplete dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6oJe.png)

Code:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    sf::WindowHandle h;
    
    sf::Time t = sf::microseconds(10);

    
    std::cout << "hello";
    
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Me/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Test'
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows/test.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Me/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Test'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows/main.o.d"
g++    -c -g -DSFML_STATIC -I/C/SFML-2.5.1/include -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows/test build/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows/main.o -L/C/SFML-2.5.1/lib -lsfml-audio-s-d -lsfml-graphics-s-d -lsfml-window-s-d -lsfml-system-s-d
build/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\Me\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Test/main.cpp:29: undefined reference to `sf::microseconds(long long)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows/test.exe] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Me/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Test'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Me/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Test'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Comment: Ah I figured it out, I downloaded the wrong version of SFML (visual c++ instead of the 5.1.0 codeblocks one). My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot, I was using the wrong SFML build, I downloaded the Visual C++ 2017 one instead of the one for 5.1.0 TDM.